# PostgreSQL pattern matching with LIKE clause returns incorrect results

Tags: postgresql

I'm writing a PostgreSQL query to search for client names from the database table using the LIKE clause. However, I notice that the query gives the expected results if the search term is entered slowly and if typed in very fast, it does read the entire word but the results displayed are only for the first letter of the word entered. Please find my query below:

```
SELECT
    i.id,
    i.at::date,
    TRIM(CONCAT(hc.first,' ', hc.family)) as billingname
FROM invoice i
LEFT JOIN clients hc ON i.c_id = hc.id
WHERE (
        (LOWER(TRIM(CONCAT(hc.first,' ',hc.family))) LIKE LOWER($1))
     OR (LOWER(hc.first) LIKE LOWER($1))
     OR (LOWER(hc.family) LIKE LOWER($1))
     OR (CAST(i.id AS TEXT) LIKE $1)
)
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
```

If I search for 'Clive', it gives the names that start with 'c' and not otherwise.  And the following is is what the terminal displays on calling the API in my application when I type in 'clive'.
`INFO     2019-03-29 09:30:08,722 module.py:880] default: "POST /api/query?q=%5B%5B%22searchName%22%2C%22cliv%25%22%5D%5D HTTP/1.1" 200 166`

`INFO     2019-03-29 09:30:08,909 module.py:880] default: "POST /api/query?q=%5B%5B%22searchName%22%2C%22clive%25%22%5D%5D HTTP/1.1" 200 166`

`INFO     2019-03-29 09:30:10,326 module.py:880] default: "POST /api/query?q=%5B%5B%22searchName%22%2C%22c%25%22%5D%5D HTTP/1.1" 200 27212`

Is this a LIKE clause performance issue or something wrong with my query? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I don't see no `LIKE` in the SQL query, let alone a `WHERE`. It also seems like the problem isn't related to the SQL part but the part that reads the user input and sends the query to the database. You should post the relevant code doing that and retag the question with the language used for that.

Comment: Apologies @sticky bit,  I've edited the query. I'll check the code that reads the query and update soon.

Comment: Yes, this is not a database problem. By the way, this query can never perform well. Avoid `OR`. Redesign your search procedure, or you will suffer once you have more than a couple of rows in your database.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Could you please elaborate on why to avoid OR and how to go about it further? I'm still trying to get my head around on databases and SQL queries. Thanks

Comment: I meant [this](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/avoid-or-for-better-performance/). Turning it into a `UNION` of 4 queries will allow you to use indexes.

Comment: Thank you @LaurenzAlbe.